# error "Use of uninitialized value in print at line" while getting html text from website using perl

Tags: perl

i wrote simple program to get html code from website.
this code work for some website and for some it does not.
e.g.

DOESNT WORK

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
sub main{
print "downloading...\n";
print get ("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
print "Finished..\n";
}
main();
```

WORKS

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
sub main{
print "downloading...\n";
print get ("https://www.google.com/");
print "Finished..\n";
}
main();
```

for wiki page it gives an error and for google page it does not.
What am i missing here.
Btw i am new to perl.

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking for errors. As [`LWP::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) suggests `get()` return value has to be defined,

```
my $content = get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

or

```
my $content = get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page") 
  // die "Couldn't get it!";

print $content;
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to whay it is failing/where it is failing so that i can correct it and get the code i  want using perl..
When i use getstore, it does not even error out but i do not get the  page i want. It completes without error but no page is saved.

Comment: @Nomad [This module is meant for people who want a simplified view of the libwww-perl library. It should also be suitable for one-liners. If you need more control or access to the header fields in the requests sent and responses received, then you should use the full object-oriented interface provided by the **LWP::UserAgent** module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you will need several attempts to download your webpage of interest.
If you are on Linux, you can use instead `system("wget -T 10 -q -N --unlink -O $savepath $url")`